# Textarea count words on click | change | keuyup as well as when text area is filled in by a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find a way to count the words in a Textarea in all these cases:

> - Paste content ✔
> - Type content ✔
> - Just click inside the text area ✔
> - Fill in the text area by a button click ❌

The first 3 cases I already cover, but somehow I cannot succeed with the case when you click on a button with a predefined text that is inserted into the Textarea.

**This is the HTML I have**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="answer">Answer </label>
<span style="display: none" id="qmsg">lenght:</span> 
<span class="badge badge-danger" style="display: none" id="improve">Needs improvement</span>
<span class="badge badge-warning"  style="display: none" id="moderate">Moderate</span>
 <span class="badge badge-info"  style="display: none" id="good">Good</span>
 <span class="badge badge-success"  style="display: none" id="awesome">Awesome</span>
<textarea name="answer" id="answer" class="form-control vorspeise" rows="3" placeholder="Type your answer here"></textarea>
 <button class="btn btn-info" href="#" onClick="autoFill('Some text to be inserted in the text area'); return false;" role="button" type="button">Add as answer</button>
</div>
```

**This is the JS I came up with**

```
function autoFill(vorspeise) {
  $('.vorspeise').val(vorspeise);
  $('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true)
}
$('textarea').on('keyup change click', function() {
  // count words
  var words = $(this).val().split(/\s+/).length;
  if (words < 3) {
    document.getElementById('qmsg').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('improve').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('moderate').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('good').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('awesome').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (words > 3 & words <= 5) {
    document.getElementById('qmsg').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('improve').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('moderate').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('good').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('awesome').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (words > 5 & words <= 7) {
    document.getElementById('qmsg').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('improve').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('moderate').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('good').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('awesome').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (words > 7) {
    document.getElementById('qmsg').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('improve').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('moderate').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('good').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('awesome').style.display = 'inline';
  } else {
    content = $(this).val();
  }
});
```

I thought that using `keyup change click` in the function will also catch the click that comes from a button. But it just catches the click within the texarea.

I have a [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/largan/uvgbd79j/39/)

p.s: I am sure that there is a better and cleaner way to write the JS... I am just not very good with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for the  [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event to catch everything, also pasting and other oddball input methods.

Also in your `autoFill` function, you need to trigger an event. That can be `change`, but since you're listening to `input`, trigger the `input` event.

```js
function autoFill(vorspeise) {
  $('.vorspeise').val(vorspeise);
  $('.vorspeise').trigger('input');
  $('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true)
}
$('textarea').on('input', function() {
  // count words
  var words = $(this).val().split(/\s+/).length;
  if (words < 3) {
    document.getElementById('qmsg').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('improve').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('moderate').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('good').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('awesome').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (words > 3 & words <= 5) {
    document.getElementById('qmsg').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('improve').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('moderate').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('good').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('awesome').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (words > 5 & words <= 7) {
    document.getElementById('qmsg').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('improve').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('moderate').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('good').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('awesome').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (words > 7) {
    document.getElementById('qmsg').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('improve').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('moderate').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('good').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('awesome').style.display = 'inline';
  } else {
    content = $(this).val();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="answer">Answer </label>
<span style="display: none" id="qmsg">lenght:</span> 
<span class="badge badge-danger" style="display: none" id="improve">Needs improvement</span>
<span class="badge badge-warning"  style="display: none" id="moderate">Moderate</span>
 <span class="badge badge-info"  style="display: none" id="good">Good</span>
 <span class="badge badge-success"  style="display: none" id="awesome">Awesome</span>
<textarea name="answer" id="answer" class="form-control vorspeise" rows="3" placeholder="Type your answer here"></textarea>
 <button class="btn btn-info" href="#" onClick="autoFill('Some text to be inserted in the text area'); return false;" role="button" type="button">Add as answer</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that did it... So easy...I will remember that. Thanks